# Unable to configure folder permissions in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, file, ubuntu, permissions, vps

I found many related questions and tried to solve the issue but I was not successful. Actually I created an user named "amit" and assigned the group "www-data". I gave permission to the folder using this method

```
sudo chown -R :www-data /var/www
sudo chmod g+w /var/www
sudo adduser amit www-data
```

Change folder and file permission recursively:
To change all the directories to 755 (-rwxr-xr-x):

```
find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

To change all the files to 644 (-rw-r--r--):

```
find /var/www -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

But in joomla system info when i check i get all directories as non writable. 
So I changes this command to

```
sudo chown -R  www-data:www-data /var/www
```

Surprisingly this worked. 
I need to know why the created user didn't work but this one worked, where did I miss something?

Comment: Did you verify the output of "joomla system info"? What does `ls -l` say about the write permissions? What does your shell say if you try to write to the directories in question as user *amit*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying `chmod 755` (rwxr-xr-x) for directories and `chmod 644` (rw-r--r--) for files just makes the writable for the *owner*, but not for the *group*. If you want to grant the *group* write permissions then you need `775` and `664`.

Comment: But whether this command --sudo adduser amit www-data --does not make it owner of that folder.

Comment: Of course not, it just creates a user called *amit* and adds him to the group *www-data*. Only one user can be the owner of a file.